# how to select a field with a dinstinct with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to do something like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CATEG) FROM TABLE;
```

I tried :

```
{
"fields" : ["category"],
"query": {
   "match_all": {}
   },"aggs":{
        "by_category": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "category"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but don't work.

In my java code, i do

```
ElasticSearchInstance instance = ElasticSearchInstance.getInstance();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("{\"fields\" : [\"category\"],"
        + "\"size\":0,\"aggs\":{ "
        + "        \"by_category\": { "
        + "           \"terms\": { "
        + "                \"field\": \"category\",\"size\":0 "
        + "  }  }  } "
        + "}");

    SearchResult searchResult = instance.execute("String", stringBuilder.toString());
```

And my searchResult is :

```
{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":0.0,"hits":[]},"aggregations":{"by_category":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[]}}}
```

My result should be "Blues" and "Other".

Any ideas ?

Comment: What response do you get and what makes you think that it's not correct? The `terms` aggregation is exactly what you need to use to achieve what you want.

Comment: i change my question

Comment: Your query seems fine, but i am not sure about your java code. Can you print created json before you send it? Also try use this query using some rest client, for example Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found it.

My query is :

```
   {
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "category": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my java code, I use :

```
Search.Builder searchBuilder = new Search.Builder(stringBuilder.toString());

SearchResult searchResult = instance.execute(searchBuilder);
List<Entry> res = searchResult.getAggregations().getTermsAggregation("category").getBuckets();
```

I loop on my list to get the key !!

Answer (score 0):

This could help you

SearchRequestBuilder srb =  ClientInstance.getInstance().getClient().prepareSearch();

srb.setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()).addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("by_category").field("category").size(0).order(Terms.Order.term(true))